# React useState() hook with large array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Using React hooks, if we need to update one element of a large state array, is it an anti-pattern to modify the state directly then call set with it?  Or is it necessary to make a copy of a huge array first to pass to set()?  I would like to avoid copying a large array on every state change.  Is the below code bad?

```
const [bigArray, setBigArray] = useState(Array(SOME_HUGE_NUMBER).fill(false));

bigArray[15] = true;
setBigArray(bigArray);
```

Comment: Please explain further, what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: My question isn't so much about achieving something in a particular program, I just want help understanding why we can't modify the current state and pass that to the setState function.  Perhaps an example of what can go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not modify state directly, it may lead to bugs. So best practice is to clone the array and then modify that value.

If you don't use that variable it will be automatically garbage collected, so it should not impact performance. Consider following example:

```
const bigArrayTmp = [... bigArray] ; 
bigArrayTmp[15] = true; 
setBigArray(bigArrayTmp);
```

After this code if `bigArrayTmp` is not being used it will be garbage collected. So won't take your memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Khatri!  I imagine this is a very common error of people new to React.  It would be nice if a linter bundled with create-react-app would warn of it.

Comment: yeah, one day may be in future.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to modify a constant variable like state in React. Try cloning the array first before setting it.

```
let newArr = [...bigArray]
newArr[15] = true
setBigArray(newArr)
```